# Create an object passing another one using the django admin application

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model object Post, which is a basic blog post model object, and a model object PostReview, which is a blog post review model.

I would like to use the admin django application to create a PostReview object based on an associated Post object.

So for example, if my post's content is equal to "blablabla", and I add a review about this post, my associated post review's content should be equal to "blablabla" too in my form when I create it so I can edit it without editing the original post's content.

I don't even know if it's possible to do it using the admin application.

Do you guys have some advices ?

Comment: You can use an inline model admin to accomplish that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Comment: I thought about that but I'd like to permit to an user to create or edit a PostPreview but not to edit a Post. Then it would be preferable to edit the PostPreview away from the Post form.

Comment: Are you wanting to use Django admin to edit the `PostReview` instances?

Comment: Yes exactly. I'd like to create or edit a PostReview instance in the django admin without having the permissions to edit anything else. Like there was "corrector" user role.

Comment: You can always use a custom view and link to your child object from the parent change list. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites will get you started on adding custom views.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'm going to try that.